# Win32/C++: Program started minimized shows generic icon in taskbar flyout preview - how do I set my own image or fix it?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

When you hover the mouse over taskbar buttons in Win10 you get a preview of that Window in a flyout.  However if I start my program minimized it shows a generic icon (if I then restore it, the preview is updated and works minimized or not - so on startup is the key).

How do I have it show what the window will look like when restored or set my own image to use so this doesn't happen?  It's okay if my own image is the only one that ever shows.  I wouldn't mind disabling the preview on the flyout either (I do need the flyout because I use use toobar buttons on it).

I see `ITaskbarList3::SetThumbnailClip()` but that would have the same issue.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Found this is controlled by the DWM (Desktop Window Manager) via `dwmapi`.  Examples of use is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/dwm-sample-customizethumbnail?redirectedfrom=MSDN)